# Devise and Users Route Confilect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I get the following clicking that link

```
<%= link_to "(#{User.count_friend_requests(current_user)}) Friends Requests", :controller => "users", :action=>"friend_requests"%>
```

i get that error

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Registrations#edit
No route matches {:action=>"friend_requests", :controller=>"devise/users", :format=>"1"}
```

routes

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'my'
resources :users, :only => [:friend_requests] do 
  get "friend_requests", :on => :collection 
end
```

users_controller

```
def friend_requests
    @frnds =  User.find_friend_requests(current_user)
end
```

[image: rake routes]

Comment: Can you provide a "rake routes" output? I can bet that devise_for creates routes like devise/users and resources :users creates routes like localhost:3000/users/friend_requests

Comment: See the edit please, you are right ,i cannot find a solution for that.

Comment: Could you try the named route instead? `friend_requests_users_path`?

Comment: Thanks you very much @Leito :D .

Comment: Did it work? I have a last question to formulate an answer? Where you calling that link from inside a view from a Devise controller?

Comment: yes it works, i called it in layouts/application.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

Heh, you've mounted devise with prefix `/my/`, so your routes are like

```
/my/users/..
```

and `resources :users` mounts your code without any prefix.

You should remove prefix `my` or or change your `resources` to

```
scope "my" do
  resources :users, :only => [:friend_requests] do 
    get "friend_requests", :on => :collection 
  end
end
```

to get path like `/my/users/friend_requests/`

Also I see that rails looks for your method in **devise/users** (not in your users) controller

```
No route matches {:action=>"friend_requests", :controller=>"devise/users", :format=>"1"}
```

If you want to patch it, you should take a look how to patch a devise's users controller.